# Is the algebra dual to a graded coalgebra graded?

Tags: abstract-algebra, dual-spaces, coalgebras, graded-algebras

Given a graded coalgebra $C = \bigoplus_{n\geq 0} C_n $ with coproduct

$$\Delta : C_n \to \bigoplus_{i=0}^n C_i\otimes C_{n-i} $$

must we have that the dual $C^* = \bigotimes_{n\geq  0}C_n^*$ is a graded algebra i.e. the product is a map

$$ C_i^*\otimes C_j^* \to C_{i+j}^* $$

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think you'd have to take the subalgebra of "continuous" functionals such that $\phi(C_n) = 0$ for sufficiently large $n$.  Then I believe that would be graded with the $n$-degree part being the functionals with support on $C_n$.  (Not confident enough in this guess to post it as an answer...)

Comment: (And then the full dual would look like a completion of this subalgebra with respect to the grading.)

Comment: Set $A_n = \hom_k(C_n,k)$ and consider the canonical map followed by the dual of $\Delta$
$$A_i\otimes A_j\to \hom_k(C_i\otimes C_j,k)\to \hom_k(C_n,k)=A_n.$$
What can sometimes fail is dualizing an algebra to a coalgebra since the first map may not be invertible.

Comment: An example of this that I *am* fairly familiar with: suppose $M$ is a free module of rank $n$, with basis $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, and $C = S^\cdot(M)$ with the coalgebra structure induced by $x \in M \mapsto 1 \otimes x + x \otimes 1$.  Then $C^*$ is isomorphic to the formal *divided* power series in $t_1, \ldots, t_n$ (i.e. the monomials formally represent $t^{[I]} = t_1^{[i_1]} \cdots t_n^{[i_n]} = \frac{t_1^{i_1} \cdots t_n^{i_n}}{i_1! \cdots i_n!}$).  And the subring of divided power polynomials *is* naturally graded.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff The issue with that is that $\sum_i A_i$ is not all of $C^*$, it's only the subalgebra of continuous functionals.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I know. But the OP is taking the *graded dual*, not the whole dual, as I see it.